# InfoPath form locked SP 2010

Tags: 2010, infopath

I have a InfoPath form in SharePoint 2010, which deploys fine on my dev server but when I try and deploy to my live site it give me this error:

> Unknown error has occurred. The form template has been published to
>   the server but it can only be opened in InfoPath filler

After digging around in the logs I find this:

> Error message: The file
>   "/FormServerTemplates/PerformanceDevelopment121.xsn" is locked for
>   exclusive use by user

I don't have a clue whats going on, if I change the name of the form it still gives me the same error. Also the user it spits out is my account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locks on files appear when you are using a client application to edit the file. This is normal and expected

Sometimes the lock goes away after around 10 min after you close the client application

Try one of the following ways to unlock the file if it remains locked

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/12/the-file-FILEURL-is-locked-for-exclusive-user-by-USER.html

http://think4code.blogspot.in/2012/07/sharepoint-2010-file-is-locked-for.html